# whois validation for SSL certificate for a private domain registration

Tags: ssl, dns, ssl-certificate, domain-name

I registered a domain with godaddy and I chose to also get domain privacy so people won't know where I live by doing a whois query.

When I read on how to acquire an SSL EV certificate for the domain, it says they will need to validate that the website is my own by doing a whois on it and match the details.

Is it possible to get a SSL certificate with the domain details being private?
is it possible to get the certificate without having formed a company?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EV validates company info., so EV without company makes no sense. What you may have is a domain-validated certificates. The latter can be validated without whois (via email etc.).